# WPF project DarkMode and LightMode problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Wpf C#.net project.

I wanted to make to do list project and I have problem.

in my project I use registerykey to theme names and then I retrive them and use them in my project but I have a serious problem and my problem is when I clicked on the button , the button theme will change but the main window won't change.

Please help me to fix this problem.
This the peace of code that I used to create and set and retrieve registry key :

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
namespace HiPlanner.Classes
{
    public class General_Info_Class01
    {
        public double SysMonSizeWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        public double SysMonSizeHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

        public byte ThemeRegisteryNum()
        {
            RegistryKey ThemeStatusRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SoftWare/HiPlanner");
            Byte Result = byte.Parse(ThemeStatusRegKey.GetValue("ThemeNumber").ToString());
            ThemeStatusRegKey.Close();
            return Result;
        }

        public void SetThemeRegNumBtnMethod(byte ThemeNo)
        {
            RegistryKey ThemeRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SoftWare/HiPlanner",true);
            ThemeRegKey.SetValue("ThemeNumber", ThemeNo);
            ThemeRegKey.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

this is the user control i created as a dark and light theme button :

design Code :

```
<UserControl x:Class="HiPlanner.DesignFiles.UserControls.ThemeStatusButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HiPlanner.DesignFiles.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="TSBTNMainGrid" Style="{StaticResource TSBTNGridStyle}">
        <Button x:Name="ThemeStatusBTN" Style="{StaticResource StatusBTN-WhiteMode}" Click="ThemeStatusBTN_Click">
            <Border x:Name="StatusCircleBorder" Style="{StaticResource StatusBorder-WhiteMode}">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <Image x:Name="ThemeStatusBtnImg" Style="{StaticResource StatusBtnImgStyle-WhiteMode}"/>
            </Border>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

design dictionary :

<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HiPlanner.DesignFiles.DesignDictionaries">

    <!--Start Status Button Style-->


    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="TSBTNGridStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="110"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality"/>
    </Style>
    
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="StatusBTN-WhiteMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#005DDE" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00A8DE" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="20">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="StatusBTN-DarkMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1A1D24"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#005DDE" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00A8DE" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="20">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="StatusBorder-WhiteMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#005DDE" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00A8DE" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E3E3E3"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#D1D1D1" BlurRadius="10" Direction="360" Opacity="1" RenderingBias="Quality" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="StatusBorder-DarkMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#002136"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#002A45"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#002136" BlurRadius="10" Direction="360" Opacity="1" RenderingBias="Quality" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,50,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="StatusBtnImgStyle-WhiteMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality"/>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/HiPlanner;component/DesignFiles/Photos/StatusBtn-WhiteMode.png"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="StatusBtnImgStyle-DarkMode">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality"/>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/HiPlanner;component/DesignFiles/Photos/StatusBtn-DarkMode.png"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
    <!--END Status Button Style-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

the c# code behind of button :

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HiPlanner.DesignFiles.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ThemeStatusButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ThemeStatusButton : UserControl
    {
        Classes.General_Info_Class01 GeneralInfo = new Classes.General_Info_Class01();
        Style ThemeStatusBtnStyleWhiteMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBTN-WhiteMode");
        Style ThemeStatusBtnStyleDarkMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBTN-DarkMode");
        Style ThemeStatusBorderStyleWhiteMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBorder-WhiteMode");
        Style ThemeStatusBorderStyleDarkMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBorder-DarkMode");
        Style ThemeStatusImgStyleWhiteMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBtnImgStyle-WhiteMode");
        Style ThemeStatusImgStyleDarkMode = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("StatusBtnImgStyle-DarkMode");


        public ThemeStatusButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetDefaultThemeBTnTheme();
        }

        private void SetDefaultThemeBTnTheme()
        {
            if (GeneralInfo.ThemeRegisteryNum() == 0)
            {
                ThemeStatusBTN.Style = ThemeStatusBtnStyleWhiteMode;
                StatusCircleBorder.Style = ThemeStatusBorderStyleWhiteMode;
                ThemeStatusBtnImg.Style = ThemeStatusImgStyleWhiteMode;
            }
            else if (GeneralInfo.ThemeRegisteryNum() == 1)
            {
                ThemeStatusBTN.Style = ThemeStatusBtnStyleDarkMode;
                StatusCircleBorder.Style = ThemeStatusBorderStyleDarkMode;
                ThemeStatusBtnImg.Style = ThemeStatusImgStyleDarkMode;
            }
            else
            {
                ThemeStatusBTN.Style = ThemeStatusBtnStyleWhiteMode;
                StatusCircleBorder.Style = ThemeStatusBorderStyleWhiteMode;
                ThemeStatusBtnImg.Style = ThemeStatusImgStyleWhiteMode;
            }
        }

        private void ThemeStatusBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (GeneralInfo.ThemeRegisteryNum() == 0)
            {
                GeneralInfo.SetThemeRegNumBtnMethod(1);
                ThemeStatusBTN.Style = ThemeStatusBtnStyleDarkMode;
                StatusCircleBorder.Style = ThemeStatusBorderStyleDarkMode;
                ThemeStatusBtnImg.Style = ThemeStatusImgStyleDarkMode;

<-- problem is here -->

                RunMainWindowThemeChecker();

<-- problem is here -->

            }
            else
            {
                GeneralInfo.SetThemeRegNumBtnMethod(0);
                ThemeStatusBTN.Style = ThemeStatusBtnStyleWhiteMode;
                StatusCircleBorder.Style = ThemeStatusBorderStyleWhiteMode;
                ThemeStatusBtnImg.Style = ThemeStatusImgStyleWhiteMode;
                RunMainWindowThemeChecker();
            }
        }
<-- problem is here -->
        private void RunMainWindowThemeChecker()
        {
            MainWindow MyMainWindow = new MainWindow(0);
            MyMainWindow.SetWindowTheme();
        }

<-- problem is here -->

    }
```

the main window code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using HiPlanner;


namespace HiPlanner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Classes.General_Info_Class01 GeneralInfo = new Classes.General_Info_Class01();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserResizeWindow();
            SetWindowTheme();
        }

        public MainWindow(byte none)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void UserResizeWindow()
        {

            double UserSysMonSizeWidth = GeneralInfo.SysMonSizeWidth;
            double UserSysMonSizeHeight = GeneralInfo.SysMonSizeHeight;
            Style FullHDStyle = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("FullHDWindowStyle");
            Style HDStyle = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("HDWindowStyle");

            if (UserSysMonSizeWidth >= 1920 && UserSysMonSizeHeight >= 1080)
            {
                MainWindow01.Style = FullHDStyle;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow01.Style = HDStyle;
            }

        }
<-- problem is here -->
        public void SetWindowTheme()
        {

            Classes.General_Info_Class01 SecGeneralinfo = new Classes.General_Info_Class01();
            Style WhiteModeTheme = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("MainBorderStyle-WhiteMode");
            Style DarkModeTheme = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("MainBorderStyle-DarkMode");
            Style WhiteModeLogoIcon = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("LogoBorderStyle-WhiteMode");
            Style DarkModeLogoIcon = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("LogoBorderStyle-DarkMode");
            Style WhiteModeLogoText = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("LogoTextLBL");
            Style DarkModeLogoText = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("LogoTextLBL-DarkMode");

            if (SecGeneralinfo.ThemeRegisteryNum() == 0)
            {
                MainWindowBorder.Style = WhiteModeTheme;
                LogoBorder.Style = WhiteModeLogoIcon;
                LogoTextLabel.Style = WhiteModeLogoText;
            }
            else if (SecGeneralinfo.ThemeRegisteryNum() == 1)
            {
                MainWindowBorder.Style = DarkModeTheme;
                LogoBorder.Style = DarkModeLogoIcon;
                LogoTextLabel.Style = DarkModeLogoText;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindowBorder.Style = WhiteModeTheme;
                LogoBorder.Style = WhiteModeLogoIcon;
                LogoTextLabel.Style = WhiteModeLogoText;
            }

        }

        private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }

        private void Testbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.AddPlanWin Addplan = new Windows.AddPlanWin();
            Addplan.ShowDialog();
        }

<-- problem is here -->
    }
}
```

I know its long but please help me.

As a matter of fact I want to know how can I change main  window theme on real time like the button?

Best regards to anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done, and you might just need to look into it a little bit more, is using Dynamic resources vs static.  In my application, I have a resource dictionary much like you.  However, I have two different "theme" color schemes for ADA 508 color compliance purposes.  One color scheme allows for gradient themes, another is more flat/fixed colors.

In each of the respective "ResourceDictionaries", I have my colors defined with the same name.  What you are doing is an explicit white vs dark context.

When I click the button to swap between gradient vs ADA compliant, I just load the respective resource dictionary and those newly loaded color values win when the forms are created / refreshed.

Something like this snippet... I actually have more, but just showing... I have my default "MyColors.xaml" loaded by default with the application.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/MyConverters.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/MyImages.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/MyColors.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, in the MyColors.xaml, I might have

```
<SolidColorBrush po:Freeze="True" x:Key="BrushWindowTitleBar" Color="#FFA0A0A0" />

<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient1">#FF303030</Color>
<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient2">#FF404040</Color>
<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient3">#FF505050</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LGBMainWindowBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient1}" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient2}" Offset="0.45" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient3}" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

etc...

Then, in my MyColors508.xaml, I would use same color names, but have different values

```
<SolidColorBrush po:Freeze="True" x:Key="BrushWindowTitleBar" Color="#FF545454" />

<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient1">#FF303030</Color>
<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient2">#FF333333</Color>
<Color x:Key="MainWindowGradient3">#FF383838</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LGBMainWindowBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient1}" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient2}" Offset="0.45" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainWindowGradient3}" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Then, a method in my code to swap out... based on the naming convention of my files in the resources of "MyColors.xaml" vs "MyColors508.xaml" and I just load the alternate...

```
    public static void ChangeColorScheme(bool show508ColorCompliance)
    {
        _show508ColorCompliance = show508ColorCompliance;

        // do we or not show the 508 color compliance theme of colors
        var PackColorScheme = @"pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/MyColors{0}.xaml";
        var _uriPath = new Uri(
            string.Format(PackColorScheme, _show508ColorCompliance ? "508" : ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        try
        {
            dict.Source = _uriPath;
            var app = Application.Current;
            app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced dark mode the first time when creating a UserControl and this is how I fixed it using and answer from Visual studio documentation [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xaml-designer-dont-work-with-usercontrols-when-usi/854384)

> User control are transparent by default. A solution has been provided
> on the ticket.  Alternatively, you can add **d:Background=“White”**
> starting with d16.8 on the user control if you want to change the
> background color of that user control.